# closure is not equal to set of all limit of sequence

Tags: general-topology

I can not think for an example of a subset of Hausdorff topological space, such that closure of that set not equal to set of all limit of sequence from the set.

Comment: I can. No, but seriously: Sequences are countable. Think of countability properties of the topology. You have covered those in your course?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: You want a space $X$ that is not first countable. If $p\in X$ has no countable local base, consider the set $A=X\setminus\{p\}$.

- Is $p\in\operatorname{cl}A$?
- Is $p$ the limit of a sequence in $A$?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can you please give me a hint of finding a space which is Hausdorff but not first countable.

Comment: @Junu: Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and fix a point $p\in X$. Make every point of $X\setminus\{p\}$ isolated. Now what’s the absolute minimum collection of open nbhds that $p$ has to have in order for the space to be Hausdorff?

Answer (score 3):

The linear order subspace $[0, \omega_1) \subset [0, \omega_1]$ is another counterexample. Its clousre is $[0, \omega_1]$, however, the set of all limit of sequence from $[0, \omega_1)$ is still $[0, \omega_1)$, since $\omega_1$ hasn't a sequence from $[0, \omega_1)$ which converges to it.